# Download existing file from server to client using php

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to make a distant client able to download an existing file(csv) named "source.csv" in my local machine using php.
After downloading the file the client should have a file named `sourceCopy.csv`with the same content as the source file.

Here's what I've tried :

```
$file_url = 'source.csv';

header('Content-Type: application/csv');

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="sourceCopy.csv"');

readfile($file_url);
```

The file is downloaded but it doesn't match the source file !

Comment: The content or file name does not match?

Comment: `header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="sourceCopy.csv"');`

Comment: The content isn't the same

Comment: That’s practically impossible, what are the differences?

Comment: Are you sure that `$file_url` matches location where desired file is located? Maybe client have some other file `sourceCopy.csv` and it's saved as `sourceCopy (1).csv`?

Comment: Try using `text/csv` @ElamriAmine